# Trail of particles from a point to TNT

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have a map where I spawn Primed TNT then teleport it to a random Mushroom Cow which is invisible to make 100% random explosion. Now I want to make a particle trail from an orb kind of block in the center of the map to the exploding Mooshroom to simulate some kind of rocket.

I would like to use the particles from burning torches. Is this possible?

edit: I know how to summon entities but I don't know how to summon particles

edit 2: I was thinking about using a zombie for villager tracking. If there is a way to send a zombie through the air then it would be possible by villager tracking. The only problem would be to generate the zombie and make him walk to the villager within 2 ticks (The time used to summon the TNT and teleport it to the mushroom or in this case the villager)

Comment: Have you tried to do this on your own?  Or is this just an idea you want to use, but haven't tried yet?

Comment: I haven't tried because I have no clue what to do to make this work

Comment: I'd recommend putting in some effort of your own, then.  We're much more receptive to questions that display some effort of your own, and you getting stuck somewhere, rather than, "Hey, I have <cool idea #456384>, how can I make it work?"  Not only does it show some effort, but it also sends the message that you're willing to put in more to get it working.  Ideas are a dime a dozen.  Attempted execution is where the value is at.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand, I am Italian

Comment: Arqade tends to respond much better to questions that show at least a little effort; try to make this particle trail happen yourself.  If you get stuck, or it doesn't work exactly the way you want, then ask that question, and show us what you have, and what doesn't work the way you want it to.

Comment: you mean like this??

Comment: i'm sorry but I'm on my phone. I will try some things tomorrow around this time. I will not be able to google due to the fact that all tutorials are videos which take a lot of my precious internet

Comment: Drawing constant straight line to random spot is not an easy problem but mob's pathfinding AI such as zombies chasing villagers could be used. Particles can be spawned with the /particle command. http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Commands#particle

Comment: it can also be done by using fireworks like in hypixels map called haunted mansion where he shoots from a skelleton to a player.  the problem here is that the situation is quite different because firework is an entity and hipixel also does not explayn how its done

Comment: Do you want a consistent line of particles from the orb to the TNT, or would occasionally "blips" work good enough for this purpose? I could write an answer of how to do tracking like in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vAC6mfrfLqs), which can go through walls/air (doesn't use mob AI).

Comment: a line would be better but at least some blips is a beginning, right?

Answer (score 2):

When you want to start the trail of particles, use this command, with `X`, `Y` and `Z` being the coordinates of the center:

```
/summon ArmorStand X Y Z {Invisible:1,CustomName:"orb"}
```

Run these commands, in order, on a repeating/chain command block loop like the depicted:

```
/execute @e[type=ArmorStand,name=orb] ~ ~ ~ summon ArmorStand ~1 ~ ~ {Invisible:1}

/execute @e[type=ArmorStand,name=orb] ~ ~ ~ summon ArmorStand ~-1 ~ ~ {Invisible:1}  

/execute @e[type=ArmorStand,name=orb] ~ ~ ~ summon ArmorStand ~ ~1 ~ {Invisible:1} 

/execute @e[type=ArmorStand,name=orb] ~ ~ ~ summon ArmorStand ~ ~-1 ~ {Invisible:1}

/execute @e[type=ArmorStand,name=orb] ~ ~ ~ summon ArmorStand ~ ~ ~1 {Invisible:1}

/execute @e[type=ArmorStand,name=orb] ~ ~ ~ summon ArmorStand ~ ~ ~-1 {Invisible:1}

/kill @e[type=ArmorStand,name=orb]

/execute @e[type=MushroomCow,name=Mushy,c=1] ~ ~ ~ entitydata @e[type=ArmorStand,c=1] {CustomName:"orb"}

/kill @e[type=ArmorStand,name=!orb]

/execute @e[type=ArmorStand,name=orb] ~ ~ ~ /particle cloud ~ ~ ~ 0 0 0 0.02 3

/execute @e[type=MushroomCow,name=Mushy,c=1] ~ ~ ~ kill @e[type=ArmorStand,r=1]
```

A screenshot:

[image: Repeating command blocks]

It has been brought to my attention that this method is rather slow. A way to speed it up is simply to make another set of command blocks as below:

[image: More repeating command blocks]

I have tested both the functionality and the speedup method and they seem to work. However, if you try it and find a problem, please tell me and I will look into it.

Comment: @RudolfJelínek If you want to speed it up, you can extend the chain to run the loop twice in 1 tick, or even make it almost infinitely long for an almost instantaneous line.

Comment: @RudolfJelínek Currently you have command blocks nos. 1-11. Make 11 more command blocks in the same direction, and put command 1 in command block 12, command 2 in command block 13, 3 in 14, ..., and 11 in 22. To accelerate the process even more, simply add 11 more command blocks again. Unfortunately, from this computer I cannot upload screenshots, but I will try to upload one in the next 24 hrs.

Comment: @RudolfJelínek The reason its so slow, as you may or may not have already found out, is because it uses recursion. This requires a loop of commands to run, and 11 blocks are enough to be functional, but if you add more command blocks, you can make the loop run more than once in one tick,speeding up the trail of particles.

Answer (score 1):

Minecraft has a command for spawning particles (`/particle`). The wiki page for this command is mentioned [here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Particles). This allows spawning particles which has been added in 1.8. Through searching myself. I have found [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5I1laWFbZkM) command block tutorial which gives a few command examples:

`/particle name (particle pos x) (particle pos y) (particle pos z) (particle size x) (particle size y) (particle pos z) (time of particle) (amount of particles or density) (target)` 
The variables X Y and Z are the starting position and XD YD and ZD are the direction it's going in. So in your case it should be:
`/particle smoke ~ ~ ~ 1 1 1 0.01 100 @e[name=""]`

 Smoke is your effect aka the torch effect. The three `~`'s is the target's position which is mentioned at @e[name=""]. It will be best to name your mooshroom for easier targeting.

EDIT:
`/execute @e[name=Mushy] ~ ~ ~ /particle cloud ~ ~ ~ 0 1 0 0.02 100` This worked for me. I spawned a mooshroom called Mushy and this spawned particles on Mushy. I've noticed that the command block has a certain range, so make sure that it's in the range.

Comment: how do I draw the line then

Comment: that does not solve the problem. just the easy part

Comment: `/execute @e[name=Mushy] ~ ~ ~ /particle cloud ~ ~ ~ 0 1 0 0.02 100`
This worked for me. I spawned a mooshroom called Mushy and this spawned particles on Mushy. I've noticed that the command block has a certain range, so make sure that it's in the range.

Comment: put this in your awnser

Comment: Edited. Solution has been added...

Comment: That's not a line from point to point. Its just a point

Comment: That's not the question of this question, you just told me everything I allready know. The tricky part is to make the line to a variable point. I apreciate your help but you need to actualy awnser the whole question in order for a "+1" or a "thick". Please edit the question so it's worth thicking

Comment: Making an adventure map without knowing how to turn this command into a command that makes a line of particles is probably not the wisest idea. And SirMeepington's answer should work.

Comment: Or use command blocks to get the position of the TNT (assuming it is launched upwards) and create a particle on it every time the command block is executed.

Comment: there It isen't launched, it explodes after 2 ticks. Then a line of particles from a point for example from X = 100 Y = 20 Z = -100 to the RANDOM point where the TNT is at so it looks like a rocket fireing. Therefor the awnser did not work. I tried it and it does not. Inprove your awnser so it aqtually fits the question. Check the edit 2 for more information.

Answer (score -1):

Use:

```
/execute @e[name=Moosh] particle flame ~ ~ ~ 1 1 1 0.01 100
```

to make an orb on a Mooshroomcow that has a name Moosh

Or:

```
/entitydata @e[r=10] {CustomNameVisible:0}
```

To hide the cows custom name in a 10 block radius