# How to produce particle effects in Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

As the title says, How do you produce particle effects in Minecraft?

I am trying to create a 1x2 doorway filled with smoke particles. I would have a clock setup to keep reproducing these particles as well. My problem is, when creating the particle effect, the smoke lingers into a nearby corner. I however, as I stated, would like the particles to be stationary in a 1x2 door frame.

I am having trouble with one part of the command. I do not understand the "XD, "YD", and "ZD" part. What does this mean, and how would I use this section of the command? Is this what is making the particle linger into a corner, and not making it stationary?

Comment: Have you even looked through the wiki?  This is pretty basic stuff that is all on the wiki.

Comment: Indeed I have, thanks. However, when I try, I do not understand the "XD", "YD", and "ZD". When I execute the command, the particles drift into another area.

Comment: Well ask that.  It shows that you've done some research, but that you're still having trouble with something specific.

Comment: Thus, I am asking how to produce them. That is my question, as I do not understand how to. Either way, I will most likely get the same answer.

Comment: You will, however, get a better answer (and reception) if it looks like you've expended effort yourself, first. We'll probably be able to answer this, but we'd be able to answer *better* if we knew where you were stuck.

Comment: Possible dupe: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/194075/trail-of-particles-from-a-point-to-tnt

Comment: @Jake: You just said you can produce particle effects.  You can literally answer your own question at this point, because that's all you're asking.  You haven't given any other details in your question as to what your actual problem is.  I have no doubt that you're still having trouble creating particle effects _the way you want them_, but you obviously know how to create them.

Comment: Sorry about that Frank and MBraedley. I have fixed my question accordingly.

Comment: This is a much better question now about something that isn't as obvious as it should be.  My only further comment would be to add the command that you're actually using.

Answer (score 3):

XD, YD, and ZD usually mean the difference in X, Y, and Z that the particles can appear in from the coordinates that you gave. This means that rather than all being summoned at an exact point, the particles can cover an area.

For example, `/particle smoke ~ ~ ~ 10 0 0 0 100` will create a long line of particles along the X axis. `/particle smoke ~ ~ ~ 1 1 1 0 100` will create a small box.

This does not affect the movement of individual particles though, you most likely want the `<speed>` argument. If you make this 0, the particles should not move as much. Keep in mind though that many particles inherently have some small movement that is unavoidable.